# direct all webpage requests with .index.html to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to direct all requests for any URL that ends with index.html to /. I have one domain on the server.

Example:

- If someone wants "www.thissite.com/index.html--it is directed to www.thissite.com/. 
  AND
- if someone wants "www.thissite.com/**anyword**/index.html"--it is directed to www.thissite.com/.
  AND
- if someone wants "www.thissite.com/**folderdoesntexistonthissite**/index.html"--it is directed to www.thissite.com/.

What is the .htaccess code that would enable this? (Both the rewritecondition and rewriterule)

This doesn't quite do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule index\.html$ http://www.thissite.com/$1 [R=301.L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (without RewriteCond):

```
RewriteRule /index\.html$ http://www.thissite.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Maybe the Error was the Period in `[R=301.L]`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable to match in RewriteCond otherwise Apache strips out starting `/` in RewriteRule. Use below code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```